# Combine different animations with Skrollr.js for one element

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I have the following structure of my page:

```
<div id="skrollr-body">
<div class="sections-container" id="sections-portrait">
    <div class="section" id="section_1">
        Section 1
        <div class="baloon"
             data-anchor-target="#section_1 .baloon"
             data-center-top="bottom: -20%"
             data-top="bottom: 50%"
        ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section_2">
        Section 2
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section_3">
        Section 3
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section_4">
        Section 4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sections-container" id="sections-landscape"></div>
```

Notice the div with class `baloon`. I want it to go from bottom to top (which it currently does), and after a while go a little bit down. Is it possible to do it with Skrollr.js and if it is - how?

Answer (score 0):

Here's Demo [CodePen DEMO](http://s.codepen.io/CY5/debug/vKkELx) 
Well i haven't use Skrollr.js plugin but tried  without it jQuery and Css 
As Section is Shown after few second Baloon is moved from bottom to top and middle

Debounce on scroll and webtransitionend src
 Function from David Walsh:
               [transitionEnd Callback](http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback)
               [Debounce on wheel](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

```js
debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

// Function from David Walsh: http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback
function whichTransitionEvent() {
  var t,
    el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var transitions = {
    "transition": "transitionend",
    "OTransition": "oTransitionEnd",
    "MozTransition": "transitionend",
    "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
  }

  for (t in transitions) {
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
      return transitions[t];
    }
  }
}

var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();

var winH = $(window).height();
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.section').height(winH);
  var updateLay = debounce(function(e) {
    callback(e);
  }, 500);
  $(window).on('wheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    updateLay(e);

  });
  obj.textTransiton();
  animLoop();

})
var globalSetting = {
  y: 0,
  delta: 0,
  maxScroll: 0,
  moved: false
}

function callback(event) {
  var delta = Math.sign(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta) || -Math.sign(event.originalEvent.detail);

  globalSetting.y += delta * winH;

  globalSetting.delta = delta;

  obj.move(obj.textTransiton);

}

function checkScrollExtents() {

  if (globalSetting.y > 0) {
    globalSetting.y = 0;
  } else if (Math.abs(globalSetting.y) > globalSetting.maxScroll) {
    globalSetting.y = -globalSetting.maxScroll;

  }

}

function animLoop() {

  globalSetting.maxScroll = obj.selector.height() - obj.selector.find('.section:last').height();
  checkScrollExtents();
  obj.scrolls();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
}

var obj = {
  'selector': $('#skrollr-body'),
  'current': $('.current'),
  scrolls: function() {
    obj.vertical();
  },
  vertical: function() {
    obj.selector.css('transform', 'translateY(' + globalSetting.y + 'px)');

  },
  textTransiton: function() {
    var baloon = obj.current.find('.baloon');
    baloon.css('transform', 'translateY(-' + winH + 'px)');
    baloon.one(transitionEvent, function(event) {
      baloon.css('transform', 'translateY(-' + (winH / 2) + 'px)');
    });
  },
  move: function(callback) {

    if (globalSetting.delta > 0) {
      obj.Prev(callback);
    } else {
      obj.Next(callback);
    }

  },
  Prev: function(c) {
    if (obj.current.prev().length) {
      var currt = obj.current.prev();
      obj.updateCurrentModule(currt);
      setTimeout(function() {
        c();
      }, 1000);
    }
  },
  Next: function(c) {
    if (obj.current.next().length) {
      var currt = obj.current.next();
      obj.updateCurrentModule(currt);
      setTimeout(function() {
        c();
      }, 1000);
    }
  },
  updateCurrentModule: function(currt) {
    obj.current.removeClass('current');
    obj.current.find('.baloon').css({
      "-webkit-transform": "translateY(0px)"
    });
    currt.addClass('current');
    obj.current = currt;
  },

};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  transition: all 600ms ease-in !important;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-size: contain;
  min-height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.baloon {
  font-size: 10em;
  color: #020000;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.51, 0.78, 0.34) !important;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="skrollr-body">
  <div class="sections-container" id="sections-portrait">
    <div class="section current" id="section_1" style="background-image: url(http://img13.deviantart.net/83ee/i/2014/145/5/e/naruto_negative_space_poster_by_jde_studios-d7jrnhc.jpg);">

      <div class="baloon">
        Naruto
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section_2" style="background-image: url(http://www.jeffreydavidson.com.au/images/blogs/naruto-negative-space-posters/sasuke-negative-space.jpg);">
      <div class="baloon">
        Sasuke
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section_3" style="background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2f/2f/ef/2f2fefdccc4688ab3d640b65cca02d47.jpg);">
      <div class="baloon">
        Kakashi
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section_4" style="background-image: url(http://www.jeffreydavidson.com.au/images/blogs/naruto-negative-space-posters/sakura-negative-space.jpg);">
      <div class="baloon">
        Sakura
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sections-container" id="sections-landscape"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but unfortunately it's not exactly what I was looking for: I need the `baloon` to go up and down when I scroll the page. That's why the question involves Skrollr.js

Comment: yeah so in demo  provided when you scroll down  balloon in each section goes up and little bit of down